# Program won't run after tightvncserver auto start at boot. No probs if started manually

Tags: boot, remote, vnc

When remotely accessing  my Pi via tightvnc my program won't run if the tightvncserver has been started automatically at boot.

I've run the Raspbian install from the latest noobs on a R Pi 2 with a newly formatted disc..

I've installed tightvncserver and remotely access the Pi from a PC.

When I start tightvncserver manually everything is fine and I can run my program from the PC without problems

However when I run tightvncserver at boot I get an error message when I run my program from the PC (see error message below).

To make tightvncserver run at boot I've modified `/etc/rc.local` by adding the following line.

```
su - pi -c '/usr/bin/tightvncserver :1`
```

What do I need to do?

I've searched the web and found different ways of auto running tightvncserver but this seened the easiest.

Error message

```
Client is not authorized to connect to ServerClient is not authorized 
to connect to ServerTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "templight15.py", line 427, in <module>
    root = Tk()   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", 
line 1813, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, 
interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying will not work.

If you are running Jessie this should be started with a `systemd` service. I copied from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=123457&p=830506

If you are still running Wheezy there are instructions for `init.d` (which may still work).

Create a new file `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=pi
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/pi/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make executable

```
sudo chmod +x  /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
```

You can test with

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver@1.service
```

Enable with

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable vncserver@1.service
```

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=pi
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/pi/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your reply.

The R pi 2 now boots up with tightvncserver running and I can access it from my PC.

When I enter the ls command I cannot see my programs listed.

This is what I get

pi@raspberrypi2:/ $ ls
bin   dev  home  lost+found  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media       opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
pi@raspberrypi2:/ $

If I enter  “cd home” and then “ls” I get the following.

pi@raspberrypi2:/home $ ls
pi

Then I enter “cd pi” and get

pi@raspberrypi2:/home $ cd pi
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $ ls
Desktop    light.py  Public        templight15.log  Tight
Documents  Music     python_games  templight15.py   Videos
Downloads  Pictures  Templates     Testing I2C.txt  w1probes1.py
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $

My programs are here.

Running “ templight15”  produces the same error message as before.

pi@raspberrypi2:~ $ sudo python templight15.py

Importing all kinds of stuff

Finished importing stuff

Client is not authorized to connect to ServerClient is not authorized to connect to ServerTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "templight15.py", line 427, in 
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in **init**
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"
pi@raspberrypi2:~ $

Have I missed something?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with VNC and is totally incomprensible (at least to me).

Comment: HiI'm using tightvncserver.

Comment: I'm  learning how to use this exchange site and somehow managed to post some code by mistake.  Sorry.

Comment: I can run a python program on the R Pi. I can run the same program via vnc from my PC if I start tightvncserver manually on the R Pi. However I cannot run the same program via vnc if I get the R pi to start tightvncserver automatically at boot.

Comment: I hope this is a little clearer. The problem started after running the latest noobs. All suggestions greatly received.