# Raspberry Pi Wifi at Boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, wireless, raspbian-jessie, wireless-adapter

I have the Official Raspberry Pi Wifi Adaptor on Raspbian Jessie. I can scan and connect to wifi just fine but I would like to get it to connect at boot so I can instantly use the SSH and VNC servers rather than a HDMI cable and monitor.

Does anyone know how I could get the RPi to make the connection at boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Once you have set it it should connect on boot. Starting `VNC` does require configuration http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39106/8697 shows how.

Comment: Yes, I have configered VNC already, it just does not seem to let me connect with my SSH putty terminal when it first loads...

Comment: How did you configure the WiFi?

Comment: @Wilf   I just loaded a new version of raspbian Jessie, none of the files have been changed. All I had to do was click on the internet symbol on the task bar and select my network.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure the WiFi connection via `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, it should automatically connect - example file contents:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
#Set wifi network name and password here
ssid="NAME"
psk="PASSWORD"

# Protocol type can be: RSN (for WP2) and WPA (for WPA1)
#proto=WPA2

# Key management type can be: WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP (Pre-Shared or Enterprise)
#key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# Pairwise can be CCMP or TKIP (for WPA2 or WPA1)
#pairwise=TKIP

#Authorization option should be OPEN for both WPA1/WPA2 (in less commonly used are SHARED and LEAP)
#auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

You may need to [set a static IP address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/10590) though, otherwise the Pi may have a different IP address to the one you are expecting

Alternatively, if your WiFi hardware supports it, you get the Pi to make a wireless hotspot which devices could then connect to - this may use more power though (so it will drain batteries quicker etc).